# How to do audio expansion/normalization (emphasise difference between high and low)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to find way to emphasise the difference between high and low points in the audio. I can't seem to find documentation on how to do this - perhaps this can be done with ffmpeg. Would really appreciate some pointers from someone who knows more about signal processing.

Comment: Are you looking for advice as to how to code up the expander algorithm, or a library to do it?

Comment: If a library with such a capability exists I would love to know about it (I would have to do it for many files, so not by hand). Otherwise, I would like some pointers on how to implement such an algorithm.

Comment: A paper or article that talks about it would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, an *expander* is the opposite of a *compressor* *; you may have more luck finding documentation about how to implement those. They also have a lot in common with a *noise gate*.

#### The expander

The basic approach is to implement an *envelope follower*, and use the value of the envelope to scale the audio source. An envelope follower tries to track the amplitude of the audio signal.

A basic pythonic pseudocode framework looks a bit like this:

```
envelope_follower e          # some envelope follower, we'll replace this

for each sample x:
   amplitude = e.get(x)      # use the envelope follower to estimate the amplitude of e
   x = expand(x, amplitude)  # apply some expansion operation
```

At it's most basic, the `expand` operation looks like this (assuming your samples are between -1.0 and 1.0):

```
def expand(x, amplitude):
    return x * amplitude
```

There are more sophisticated approaches, for example clamping and scaling amplitude so it never drops below 0.5, or applying some non-linear function to amplitude before multiplying.

```
# just an example
def expand(x, amplitude):
    return x * clamp(1.2 * amplitude - 0.2 * (amplitude * amplitude), 0.3, 1.0)
```

#### Envelope followers

The quality of the compressor/expander depends **almost entirely on how you implement the envelope follower**.
It's not an exact science, as a very accurate envelope follower might cause some nasty audible effects in certain situations - there are trade-offs to be made.

As with all of these things, there are a lot of approaches! Here's a couple:

#### Filtered rectifier

One of the simplest approaches - particularly if you already have a library of signal processing blocks - is the *lowpass-filtered rectifier*.

It works like this:

```
class envelope_follower:
    lowpassfilter filter;

    def get(x):
        return filter.process( abs(x) )
```

The controls you get here are basically around your filter design, and lowpass cutoff. Using a simple leaky-accumulator filter will get you a long way.

#### Attack-Release follower

People usually want more control over their expander, and it's sometimes difficult to think about the actual effects of the filtered rectifier - tweaking one parameter might change a lot of its behaviour.

It's often very desirable for real-world signals for compressors/expanders to respond very quickly (for example, to a piano or drum impact), and be slow to release (so the tail of the piano note isn't suddenly cut off)

An Attack-Release follower gives more precise control by specifying a number of parameters:

- Two thresholds

  - A threshold, above which sounds should be made louder
  - A threshold, below which sounds should be made quieter (not necessarily the same threshold, but can be!)
- Two time periods:

  - How long it takes to reach full loudness when the first threshold is crossed (This is the *Attack* parameter)
  - How long it takes to reach quietness (*Release*)

One basic approach to implementing one of these is:

```
class envelope_follower:
    # Parameters required. These are just made up
    attack_threshold = 0.6
    release_threshold = 0.3
    attack_time = 10       # in samples
    release_time = 1000    # in samples

    amp = 0.0

    def get(x):
        # we still work with the absolute value.
        # You might use another measure of amplitude here like RMS
        # or even the filtered rectifier above
        a = abs(x)

        if x > attack_threshold:
          amp += (1.0 / attack_time)
        else if x < release_threshold:
          amp -= (1.0 / release_time)

        amp = clamp(amp, 0.0, 1.0)

        return amp
```

One common extension to this type of follower is to add a *Hold* parameter, that specifies a minimum length of time that the expander should be wide open. This avoids the envelope creating an audible triangle or sawtooth wave on lower-frequency signals.

An even more sophisticated approach is to do a full Attack-Decay-Sustain-Release, which lets you control the transients and is commonly used as a drum treatment.

### Getting wild

From here, you can:

- Create a smoother `expand` function
- Fairly trivially adjust the above into a Compander - a combination device that quietens low sounds, but also quietens overly-loud sounds;
- Split a signal into multiple frequency bands, and compress/expand each one separately. This is commonly done do get real in-your-face maximum amplitude during music mastering;
- Adjust Attack/Hold/Release based on the spectral content of the sound you're expanding. Very short attack/release times are fine for high-frequency signals, but sound awful for low-frequency signals;
- Add a mild saturating distortion for sounds over the threshold; this can make things *perceptually* louder, even if the signal still has same the maximum amplitude. You ideally want a saturator that doesn't affect signals under the threshold at all.

Good luck!

---

* not to be confused with MP3-style compression. A compressor squishes the dynamic range.

Comment: Wow, this is super helpful, thank you. Great overview to get me started!